# Ubuntu BASH syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm following this tutorial http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1550470 to install a GUI for Phorinix test suite installing it on Ubuntu 12.04. I already have the test suite and PHP5 installed, both running fine in the terminal but I'm now trying to create the GUI.

When running this part of the tutorial:

```
cd /usr/share/aclocal
sudo cp libtool.m4 libtool.m4~backup
sudo chmod 777 libtool.m4
(start line) sudo cat lt~obsolete.m4 ltoptions.m4 ltsugar.m4 ltversion.m4 >>libtool.m4 (end line)
sudo chmod 644 libtool.m4
```

I get the following error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `sudo'

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you need to add ';' as a commands delimeter: cd /usr/share/aclocal; sudo cp libtool.m4 libtool.m4~backup; sudo chmod 777 libtool.m4  ...

Answer (score 0):

The `(start line)` and `(end line)` markers look more like comments than they do commands that fit the rest of the script. But if they really belong, they need to be separated from the rest of the line with

```
(start line); sudo cat ... >> libtool.m4; (end line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `(start line)` and `(end line)`. The original poster added these when the forum would cut off lines in order to fit code blocks in a certain width.